# React doesn't render data coming from an api response

Tags: reactjs, axios

I've seen a lot of questions and I couldn't get the solution
here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import "./tree.css";
import "./mainTree";

class TablesTree extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.data = this.props.info;
    this.state = {
      fields: [],
      data: [],
      show: false
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    var dataGet = [];
    this.props.tables.forEach((name, i) => {
      this.getFieldsTable(name.TABLE_NAME, (err, res) => {
        if (res) {
          dataGet.push({
            TABLE_NAME: name.TABLE_NAME,
            columns: res
          });
        }
      });
    });
    this.setState({ data: dataGet });
  }
  getFieldsTable(table, callback) {
    axios
      .get(`table/columns?name=${this.data.user}&psw=${this.data.password}&schema=${this.data.schema}&table=${table}`)
      .then(response => {
        callback(null, response.data);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.data
          ? this.state.data.map((itm, i) => {
              return (
                <div>
                  <h1>{itm.TABLE_NAME}</h1>
                </div>
              );
            })
          : null}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default TablesTree;
```

I've made console.log of the this.state.data
and the data is in there, but it doesn't renders anything
I've tried a lot of soutions, but I still without rendering the data, I will apreciate your help.

Comment: `getFieldsTable` is asynchronous, so `dataGet` will be empty when you do `this.setState({data: dataGet});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few things I would change about your code, but most importantly you need to do `this.setState` after your push to `dataGet` (inside of your callback function).

Because your API call is asynchronous, you are only calling `setState` once when your component is initially mounted (and while `dataGet` is still empty).

Comment: You don;t know how thankful I'm with all your answers, I had been with this error for 2 days, thank you a lot, I will never get another error like this!! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`getFieldsTable` is asynchronous, so the `dataGet` array will be empty when you call `setState`.

You could return the promise from `getFieldsTable` and use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) on all the promises, and use the data when all of them have resolved.

**Example**

```
class TablesTree extends Component {
  // ...

  componentDidMount() {
    const promises = this.props.tables.map(name => {
      return this.getFieldsTable(name.TABLE_NAME).then(res => {
        return {
          TABLE_NAME: name.TABLE_NAME,
          columns: res
        };
      });
    });

    Promise.all(promises).then(data => {
      this.setState({ data });
    });
  }

  getFieldsTable(table) {
    return axios
      .get(`table/columns?name=${this.data.user}&psw=${this.data.password}&schema=${this.data.schema}&table=${table}`)
      .then(response => {
        return response.data;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  // ...
}
```